# Accessing Query Response is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the id from appointments table in laravel. And then checking whether the query is empty or not. Though appointments table have same data to execute the if condition but it always returns empty.
code is given below

`

```
    $chk = DB::table('appointments')->select('id')
                ->where('patient_id',$patient_id)
                ->where('doctor_id',$doctor)
                ->where('appointment_date',$appointment_date)
                ->get();

    if($chk->isNotEmpty()){
        return response()->json('failed',401);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json('success',200);
    }
```

`
it always executes else condition

Comment: Well, that implies the results are empty. `dd($chk)` to print out the value of the variable. If it's empty, figure out why.

Comment: Actually, your condition is "if it is not empty return error ". Why ?

Comment: Maybe try removing `where` calls one by one to see at what point the results are not empty anymore.

Comment: @ Wouter Florijn when I removed `where('appointment_date',$appointment_date)` it worked fine. but I need to add this

Comment: Then check the value of `$appointment_date` and the records in the database.

Comment: solved. Deleted the where condition and added again. It's crazy